# Which of the following instructions can reference a memory location that is #1000 locations from the instruction?

Tags: memory, cpu, cpu-architecture

I am working on a question from a practice computer organization exam

**The Problem:**
Which of the following instructions can reference a memory location that is #1000 locations from the instruction?
    a.ADD
    b.LD
    c.STR
    d.LEA
    e.All of the above
    f.None of the above

**My Thought Process:**

I am using  [LC-3](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~milom/cse240-Fall05/handouts/Ch05.pdf) as a reference to do this problem. I used a synonym of reference, mention from [Reference](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/refer) to make the question more clear. Now I am down to the question of which one of the following instructions can mention a memory location that is #1000 locations from the instruction. Now, evaluating the individual choices

- Add - This can reference a location that is 1000 away. Add can take data from two registers which can represent any memory location. YES!!
- LD - LD uses PC relative mode, meaning it has 9 bits for offset or can access a memory location 256 spots away from the address in the program counter register(address of next instruction). So NO!!
- STR - uses Base+Offset mode so the memory address it accesses is the address in the base register + offset6. But the address in the base register can already be 1000 memory locations away from the current instruction. So Yes!!
- LEA - computes an address like PC Relative LD. So No!! (same justification as LD)

Off my justifications above, my final answer would be a.ADD and c.STR. Does everyone agree with my answer and justifications? Did I miss one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think ADD can directly reference memory at all in LC-3.  I believe it can work either on registers (i.e. you would need to load memory into the register before performing the ADD) or with immediates.  So:

- ADD: immediate or register addressing only - no direct access to memory
- LD: 9bit PC-relative only, cannot reach an offset of 1000
- STR: base+offset only, can access memory at any address with an appropriate base address
- LEA: 9bit PC-relative only, cannot reach an offset of 1000 (and doesn't really look at the memory anyway)

Check out these slides by Cyrus Bazeghi / Andrea di Blas / Alex Holloway: https://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmpe012/Summer08/notes/06_LC3_ISA_markup.pdf.  They show the instruction flow through the architecture, which is pretty useful for understanding addressing modes.

Comment: And are you sure LEA *can* reference memory?

Comment: That's actually a good point.  It doesn't actually look at the memory, it just calculates the offset PC and sends that back to the register bank.